# PHP Azure Storage - on Table update I get: Server failed to authenticate the request

Tags: php, eclipse, azure, fiddler

Hello mighty Windows Azure developers,

I am using PHP SDK for Windows Azure in eclipse working with storage table on local compute and storage emulator

I am running this code (basically I am updating data):

```
$statistics = AzureStorageTable::connection()->retrieveEntities(self::$statisticsTableName);
    foreach($statistics as $statistic) {
        $block = $statistic->getRowKey();
        if(isset($processedLogs[$block])) {
            $processedLog = $processedLogs[$block];
            $statistic->time    = ($statistic->time + $processedLog[0]);
            $statistic->count   = ($statistic->count + $processedLog[1]);
            $statistic->average = ($statistic->time / $statistic->count);
            AzureStorageTable::connection()->updateEntity(self::$statisticsTableName,$statistic);
        }           
    }
```

I get:

> Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Exception
>
> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

It fails here in the SDK:

Storage/Table.php (615) Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table-> _changeEntity

The entity object looks like this:

```
Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_DynamicTableEntity(5) ▼ {
   "_dynamicProperties" protected => array(4) ▼ {
      "timestamp" => stdClass(3) ▼ {
         "Name" => "Timestamp" (9)
         "Type" => "Edm.DateTime" (12)
         "Value" => DateTime(3) { ... }
      }
      "time" => stdClass(3) ▼ {
         "Name" => "time" (4)
         "Type" => "Edm.Double" (10)
         "Value" => 95.899748802185
      }
      "count" => stdClass(3) ▼ {
         "Name" => "count" (5)
         "Type" => "Edm.Int32" (9)
         "Value" => 44
      }
      "average" => stdClass(3) ▼ {
         "Name" => "average" (7)
         "Type" => "Edm.Double" (10)
         "Value" => 2.1795397455042
      }
   }
   "_partitionKey" protected => "timers" (6)
   "_rowKey" protected => "%2F" (3)
   "_timestamp" protected => DateTime(3) ▼ {
      "date" => "2012-04-20 22:51:50" (19)
      "timezone_type" => 3
      "timezone" => "UTC" (3)
   }
   "_etag" protected => "W/"datetime'2012-04-20T22%3A51%3A50.483Z'"" (42)
}
```

I had the same error also when trying to delete an entity.

I have tried to create the table entity instead of getting it from the storage and then using the same object for update but it doesn't work.

I know that there might be some issue with time according to googling but my time on my system is right (I am UTC+1). Somehow the time stamp in storage is 2 hours behind the actual time but I don't know what to do about it.

I do have Fiddler2 but I have no idea how to set it up to catch communication with http://127.0.0.1:10002 (local table storage).

Any idea what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: Do you have a line of code that is passing in your account name, and also your shared key. It should look something like _$storageClient = new Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table('table.core.windows.net', 'myaccount', 'myauthkey');_. There might be an issue there.

Comment: the AzureStorageTable::connection() in my code returns new Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table(azure_getconfig("TableStorageEndpoint"), azure_getconfig("StorageAccountName"), azure_getconfig("StorageAccountKey"), false, new GlobalAzureRetryPolicy());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... it is a bug in PHP Azure SDK from: http://phpazure.codeplex.com/

I told the developers about it here: http://phpazure.codeplex.com/workitem/6901

I am adding the solution here as well:

The problem is that when I call this:

```
$entity = $storage -> retrieveEntities($tableName);
$entity -> Name = "New name;"
$storage -> updateEntity($tableName,$entity);
```

it fails giving me **Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Exception** *Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.*

The problem is that the result of retrieveEntities is *Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_DynamicTableEntity* and then updateEntity calls on it *getAzureValues* and both *$this->_dynamicProperties* and *parent::getAzureValues()* return *timestamp* which leads to an array with two timestamps which leads to the error

hot fix I made was adding this code:

```
if(isset($this->_dynamicProperties["timestamp"]))unset($this->_dynamicProperties["timestamp"]);
```

on the line before return in *getAzureValues* in *Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_DynamicTableEntity*

and then it works as a magic :]

this error is both in the old SDK and in the latest SDK from trunk

Answer (score 0):

Like you already said, the issue could be related to your system's clock not being configured correctly. But the **Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.** error could be caused by an other reason.

Trying with Fiddler2 is your best option at the moment. You could try setting Fiddler2 as proxy in your web.config (I suppose you have one even though you're working with PHP):

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy bypassonlocal="False" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888"/>
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Are you using the HTTP or HTTPS endpoint for table storage? If you're using HTTPS, you'll also need to make sure Fiddler also decrypts HTTPS traffic (via Tools > Fiddler Options).

Comment: I have added the deault proxy into configuration in web.config but Fiddler still doesnt show any communication with the local storage

Comment: doesnt show any communication with the cloud storage from local compute emulator as well